# Draw a UIView in greyscale?

Tags: ios, uiview, filter, grayscale

Is there a way to draw a given UIView (and it's subviews) in greyscale?

I'm trying to take a view hierarchy and make it look disabled without overlaying an image or switching the images used to draw each UIView in the hierarchy.

Comment: Adding a comment to my old question. There might be a solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298867/convert-image-to-grayscale

Answer (score 6):

Add a CALayer to your UIView, with the compositingFilter set to colorBlendMode:

```
let grayLayer = CALayer()
grayLayer.frame = bounds
grayLayer.compositingFilter = "colorBlendMode"
grayLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
layer.addSublayer(grayLayer)
```

Answer (score -1):

When I want to disable a view, I usually just set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` and `alpha = .5` (or some other < 1. alpha)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot draw a UIView in grayscale, but you may place a semi-transparent UIView layer on top of the whole thing to show a grayed out behavior.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431021/gray-out-view-in-iphone-how).