# Convert UIImage to grayscale keeping image quality

Tags: swift, uiimage, grayscale

I have this extension (found in `obj-c` and I converted it to `Swift3`) to get the same `UIImage` but grayscaled:

```
public func getGrayScale() -> UIImage
{
    let imgRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue).rawValue)
    context?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: imgRect)

    let imageRef = context!.makeImage()
    let newImg = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

    return newImg
}
```

I can see the gray image but its quality is pretty bad... The only thing I can see that's related to the quality is `bitsPerComponent: 8` in the context contructor. However looking at Apple's doc, here is what I get:

[image]

It shows that iOS only supports 8bpc... Thus why can't I improve the quality ?

Comment: Check your width and height to make sure the original is not 2x the size.

Comment: This is technically not an answer to your question but assuming that you want to display your gray UIImage in an UIImageView, you can add a layer to that view with a compositing filter as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67436327/5561658
This workflow has a few advantages: light, less code, can easily be toggled.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try below code:

**Note:** code Updated and error been fixed...

- Code tested in Swift 3.
- `originalImage` is the image that you trying to convert.

**Answer 1:**

```
     var context = CIContext(options: nil)
```

**Update:** `CIContext` is the Core Image component that handles `rendering` and All of the processing of a core image is done in a `CIContext`. This is somewhat similar to a `Core Graphics` or `OpenGL context`.For more info available in [Apple Doc.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cicontext/%22Apple%20Doc.%22)

```
     func Noir() {

        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") 
        currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: originalImage.image!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage 
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!,from: output!.extent)
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        originalImage.image = processedImage
      }
```

Also you need to Considered following filter that can produce similar effect

- `CIPhotoEffectMono`
- `CIPhotoEffectTonal`

**Output from Answer 1:**

[image]

**Output from Answer 2:**

[image]

**Improved answer :**

**Answer 2:** Auto adjusting input image  before applying coreImage filter

```
var context = CIContext(options: nil)

func Noir() {


    //Auto Adjustment to Input Image
    var inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
    let options:[String : AnyObject] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation:1 as AnyObject]
    let filters = inputImage!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: options)

    for filter: CIFilter in filters {
       filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
   inputImage =  filter.outputImage
      }
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage!, from: inputImage!.extent)
    self.originalImage.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

    //Apply noir Filter
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectTonal") 
    currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let output = currentFilter!.outputImage 
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    originalImage.image = processedImage

}
```

**Note:** If you want to see the better result.You should be testing your code on `real device` not in the `simulator`...

Answer (score 33):

A **Swift 4.0** extension that returns an optional `UIImage` to avoid any potential crashes down the road.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    var noir: UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") else { return nil }
        currentFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let output = currentFilter.outputImage,
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

To use this:

```
let image = UIImage(...)
let noirImage = image.noir // noirImage is an optional UIImage (UIImage?)
```

Comment: How do you use this in the code? Can you give an example usage?

Comment: Works perfectly in Swift 5.1

Answer (score 13):

Joe's answer as an `UIImage` exension for `Swift 4` working correctly for different scales:

```
extension UIImage {
    var noir: UIImage {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")!
        currentFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = currentFilter.outputImage!
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)

        return processedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Also how can we get back the original image?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha please see CodeBender's answer. I'm afraid there is no way to get original image back, as most colour information is lost after applying noir filter

Answer (score 7):

I'd use CoreImage, which may keep the quality.

```
func convertImageToBW(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")

    // convert UIImage to CIImage and set as input

    let ciInput = CIImage(image: image)
    filter?.setValue(ciInput, forKey: "inputImage")

    // get output CIImage, render as CGImage first to retain proper UIImage scale

    let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciOutput?.extent)!)

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

Depending on how you use this code, you may want to create the CIContext outside of it for performance reasons.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a category in objective c.  Note that, critically, this version takes scale into consideration.

```
- (UIImage *)grayscaleImage{
    return [self imageWithCIFilter:@"CIPhotoEffectMono"];
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithCIFilter:(NSString*)filterName{
    CIImage *unfiltered = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName];
    [filter setValue:unfiltered forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    CIImage *filtered = [filter outputImage];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgimage = [context createCGImage:filtered fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width*self.scale, self.size.height*self.scale)];
    // Do not use initWithCIImage because that renders the filter each time the image is displayed.  This causes slow scrolling in tableviews.
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimage scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgimage);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: but he's not the only person there :), thanks @arsenius

Comment: Yup, this was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 5):

All the above solutions rely on `CIImage`, while `UIImage` will often have `CGImage` as its underlying image, not `CIImage`. So it means you have to convert your underlying image into `CIImage` in the beginning, and convert it back to `CGImage` in the end (if you don't, constructing `UIImage` with `CIImage` will effectively do it for you).

Although it probably OK for many use cases, the conversion between `CGImage` and `CIImage` is not free: it can be slow, and can create a big memory spike while converting.

So I want to mention a completely different solution, that doesn't require converting image back and forth. It's using [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate), and it's perfectly described by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/converting_color_images_to_grayscale).

Here's a playground example that demonstrates both methods.

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate

extension CIImage {

    func toGrayscale() -> CIImage? {

        guard let output = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: self])?.outputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        return output
    }

}

extension CGImage {

    func toGrayscale() -> CGImage {

        guard let format = vImage_CGImageFormat(cgImage: self),
              // The source image bufffer
              var sourceBuffer = try? vImage_Buffer(
                cgImage: self,
                format: format
              ),
              // The 1-channel, 8-bit vImage buffer used as the operation destination.
              var destinationBuffer = try? vImage_Buffer(
                width: Int(sourceBuffer.width),
                height: Int(sourceBuffer.height),
                bitsPerPixel: 8
              ) else {
            return self
        }

        // Declare the three coefficients that model the eye's sensitivity
        // to color.
        let redCoefficient: Float = 0.2126
        let greenCoefficient: Float = 0.7152
        let blueCoefficient: Float = 0.0722

        // Create a 1D matrix containing the three luma coefficients that
        // specify the color-to-grayscale conversion.
        let divisor: Int32 = 0x1000
        let fDivisor = Float(divisor)

        var coefficientsMatrix = [
            Int16(redCoefficient * fDivisor),
            Int16(greenCoefficient * fDivisor),
            Int16(blueCoefficient * fDivisor)
        ]

        // Use the matrix of coefficients to compute the scalar luminance by
        // returning the dot product of each RGB pixel and the coefficients
        // matrix.
        let preBias: [Int16] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        let postBias: Int32 = 0

        vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888ToPlanar8(
            &sourceBuffer,
            &destinationBuffer,
            &coefficientsMatrix,
            divisor,
            preBias,
            postBias,
            vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags)
        )

        // Create a 1-channel, 8-bit grayscale format that's used to
        // generate a displayable image.
        guard let monoFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 8,
            colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
            renderingIntent: .defaultIntent
        ) else {
                return self
        }

        // Create a Core Graphics image from the grayscale destination buffer.
        guard let result = try? destinationBuffer.createCGImage(format: monoFormat) else {
            return self
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

To test, I used a full size of [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden_Gate_Bridge_2021.jpg) image.

```
let start = Date()
var prev = start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1

func info(_ id: String) {
    print("\(id)\t: \(start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1 - prev)")
    prev = start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1
}

info("started")
let original = UIImage(named: "Golden_Gate_Bridge_2021.jpg")!
info("loaded UIImage(named)")

let cgImage = original.cgImage!
info("original.cgImage")
let cgImageToGreyscale = cgImage.toGrayscale()
info("cgImage.toGrayscale()")
let uiImageFromCGImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageToGreyscale, scale: original.scale, orientation: original.imageOrientation)
info("UIImage(cgImage)")

let ciImage = CIImage(image: original)!
info("CIImage(image: original)!")
let ciImageToGreyscale = ciImage.toGrayscale()!
info("ciImage.toGrayscale()")
let uiImageFromCIImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImageToGreyscale, scale: original.scale, orientation: original.imageOrientation)
info("UIImage(ciImage)")
```

**The result** (in sec)

`CGImage` method took about 1 sec. total:

```
original.cgImage        : 0.5257829427719116
cgImage.toGrayscale()   : 0.46222901344299316
UIImage(cgImage)        : 0.1819549798965454
```

`CIImage` method took about 7 sec. total:

```
CIImage(image: original)!   : 0.6055610179901123
ciImage.toGrayscale()       : 4.969912052154541
UIImage(ciImage)            : 2.395193934440613
```

When saving images as JPEG to disk, the one created with CGImage was also 3 times smaller than the one created with CIImage (5 MB vs. 17 MB). The quality was good on both images. Here's a small version that fits SO restrictions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per **Joe** answer we easily converted Original to B&W . But **back to Original** image refer these code :

```
var context = CIContext(options: nil)
var startingImage : UIImage = UIImage()

func Noir() {     
    startingImage = imgView.image!
    var inputImage = CIImage(image: imgView.image!)!
    let options:[String : AnyObject] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation:1 as AnyObject]
    let filters = inputImage.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: options)

    for filter: CIFilter in filters {
        filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        inputImage =  filter.outputImage!
    }
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent)
    self.imgView.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

    //Filter Logic
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
    currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    imgView.image = processedImage
}

func Original(){ 
    imgView.image = startingImage
}
```

Comment: this is not the way to restore the origin photo. what if add filter 2 times and wanna restore to original photo? this solution is not gonna work.