# Convert UIImage colored to grayscale using CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

Tags: ios, swift, image, grayscale

I am trying to convert a UIImage to GrayScale. All it make is totally a black image.

```
func convertToGrayScale2(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageRect:CGRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let width = image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
    let imageRef = context!.makeImage()
    context?.draw(imageRef!, in: imageRect)
    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? I need help with existing code. It was working previously. Suddenly its not working.

Comment: You probably should draw into the context *before* making an image from it. Also `bytesPerRow: 0` looks wrong.

Comment: Can you write the statement for me? @Martin R

Comment: BytesPerRow : 0 is correct for this answer. I should draw before making an image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func convertToGrayScale(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let imageRect:CGRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let width = image.size.width
        let height = image.size.height

        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        //have to draw before create image

        context?.draw(image.cgImage!, in: imageRect)
        let imageRef = context!.makeImage()
        let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

        return newImage
    }
```

Comment: Changes the color, but rotates 90 degrees. Very odd.

Comment: You have to add a rotation function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function instead:

```
func convertImageToDifferentColorScale(with originalImage:UIImage, imageStyle:String) -> UIImage {
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: imageStyle)
    currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: originalImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!,from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    return processedImage
}
```

And here is the example of how you use:

```
 let newImage = convertImageToDifferentColorScale(with: UIImage(named: "0318_1")!, imageStyle: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
 testingImageView.image = newImage
```

In imageStyle part, there are several different kind of style like below:

> ```
>  CIColorCrossPolynomial
>  CIColorCube
>  CIColorCubeWithColorSpace
>  CIColorInvert
>  CIColorMap
>  CIColorMonochrome
>  CIColorPosterize
>  CIFalseColor
>  CIMaskToAlpha
>  CIMaximumComponent
>  CIMinimumComponent
>  CIPhotoEffectChrome
>  CIPhotoEffectFade
>  CIPhotoEffectInstant
>  CIPhotoEffectMono
>  CIPhotoEffectNoir
> ```

And `'CIPhotoEffectNoir'` is one choice that can give you `gray scale`.

Comment: This will not create an image with DeviceGray color space( kcGColorSpaceModelMonochrome), but kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB. If the output of this solution were to be used as a masking image cgImage.masking() e.g., it would not work, since that would require DeviceGray color space.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative maybe to use CoreImage filters. Please refer to the following [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178846/convert-uiimage-to-grayscale-keeping-image-quality) and its [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182080/5807290). Hope it helps. Happy Coding!

Comment: is that method supposed take forever and a day to execute?

Comment: no it usually does not take any noticeable time for images of normal resolution. What resolution is your image?

Comment: I was just using a picture taken with an iPhone 8. I didn't look at the size, but it wasn't very big.

Comment: Yes the image size would not be very large in that case. Maybe the issue is not due to image resolution

Comment: I can't remember what I did, but I found something a little faster.